# How to Add the Values in Columns Related to a CSV file (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm very new to coding, so apologies in advance. I have a CSV file on my computer called SouthKoreaRoads2, and the image below is an example of what it looks like ( a name, a year, and a length): [image]

Using the following code, I made a new table, based on the original data, but only including the rows with a year below 1975 (the column with the rows is called Simplified Date).

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
SouthKoreaRoads2 = pd.read_csv("SouthKoreaRoads2.csv")
SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]
```

Now, my question: how can I add up every length value (third column) within this more specific table? I can totally clarify or provide additional information, I'm just feeling really lost and would appreciate any help :)

Comment: What do you mean 'add more length value'? Pl provide more specific info

Comment: Can you show the output you want to see?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/1767c0c82607a1c367f3f7d0821cdf1c.png I want my output to be the sum of everything in the length (km) column. Mac_online, I meant I want to add all the length values in this table I've created.

Answer (score 1):

You don't create a new table but you have just filter your data.

```
SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]
```

If you want to create a new table, you have to set a new variable:

```
SKR2_1975 = SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]
```

Now if you want the total length in this new table, you can do:

```
total_length = SKR2_1975['Length (km)'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of the length value using the `sum()` function after you get the filtered result of the DataFrame

```
total = SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]["length"].sum()
```

Comment: When I used total = SouthKoreaRoads2[SouthKoreaRoads2['Simplified Date'] < 1975]["Length (km)"].sum() I ended up with 22.9234.48217.9106.8166.3301.7117.218.154194.2144.613.4416.1131.8122.6 and I'm not sure what this means. Does anyone have any ideas on where the error is?

Comment: Could you try printing out data type of each column in the data frame using `print(SouthKoreaRoads2.dtypes)`? I think `"Length (km)"` might have non-numeric data type

Comment: You can try converting the `"Length (km)"` column into float64 using `SouthKoreaRoads2["Length (km)"] = SouthKoreaRoads2["Length (km)"].astype(np.float64)` before getting the filtered result